# For any word, see constituent roots; for any root, see composite words

Tags: discussion, etymology, resources, reference, online-resources

Definition lookup in Google will show the origin or etymology of a word, usually based on root. Is there an application, web or otherwise, that returns composite words for any given root?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Oxford English Dictionary web application provides this service.

If you [look up the word *composite*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/37791) in the OED, it reveals that its etymology is:

> Etymology: < Latin *compositus*, past participle of *compōnĕre* to put together. Compare French *composite* (in Archit.). Introduced first in the architectural sense (2), the only one recognized by Johnson, 1755–73.

Then you go to its advanced search page and [look for either of those two Latin forms in the Etymology section](https://www.oed.com/search?case-sensitive=true&f_0=Etymology&f_1=Etymology&nearDistance=1&o_1=OR&ordered=false&q_0=compositus&q_1=comp%C5%8Dn%C4%95re&scope=ENTRY):

> [image: search screen example]

Which run produces 17 hits, of which the first few are:

> [image: results example]

However, this is behind a paywall because it’s meant for scholarly research.

You’ll need a library card from a participating library (such as from the UK) or from an institutional membership (like a university), or else an individual subscription of your own, which runs $90 per year for their “specially discounted” price or $295 without the discount.

Comment: Also available for free in the US through a library card at a local public library.

Comment: It’s behind a paywall because they’re lacking in innovation.